# How to add html tag to xml element

Tags: xml, http, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am just learning XML to Html from w3 school. I was successfully able to get 2 of the tags and post them on html as text. and one of them is image.

This time I want to learn how to fetech the tag with image link and preview it also ?

**Here is xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml><version>1.0</version>
<serverid>VuXmlServer</serverid>
<page>
<templateid>vuxml:detail.xml</templateid>
<title>Lagaan</title>
<topleft_logo></topleft_logo>
<topright_logo></topright_logo>
<absurl></absurl>
</page><downloadinfo>
<name>Lagaan</name>
<ca>VuXML_PARTNER</ca>
<uniqid>ID_1</uniqid>
<mastertype>webstream</mastertype>
<type>webstream</type>
<downloadtype>Buy</downloadtype>
<duration>12916</duration>
<cost>FREE</cost><filesize>
</filesize><bitrate></bitrate>
<link>http://somelinktothevidesite.com/1.html</link>
<albumart>http://guangzhou.cust.footprint.net/JemMovies/HindiMid/Posters/Lagaan.png</albumart>
<sinfo1>Aamir Khan, Gracy Singh, Rachel Shelley</sinfo1>
<sinfo2>Hindi</sinfo2>
<sinfo3></sinfo3>
<sinfo4></sinfo4>
<linfo>too long </linfo>
<description>tool long</description></downloadinfo>
<buttons><button><name>Watch Now</name>
<link>vuxml://play</link></button>
<button><name>Page up</name>
<link>vuxml://pageup</link></button>
<button><name>Page down</name>
<link>vuxml://pagedown</link></button>
<button><name>Cancel</name>
<link>vuxml://back</link></button></buttons></xml>
```

**Here is html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","1059.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("downloadinfo");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("albumart")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**code trying to add to xml** so it will print image on html

```
<img border="0" src="***LINK FROM XML***" alt="MOVIE" width="304" height="228">
```

Comment: If W3Schools teaches you to use document.write then you really should learn from a different source.

Comment: Thanks I was able to find out.